# Django formset missing id for manually rendered template

Tags: python, django

I am using django formset to submit a dynamically generated form (based on a file uploaded by the user). The template renders this form manually (I prefer this because it's easier for me to work on style+HTML together in template). On submitting the form, I get an error that `id is a required field`. My form template looks like this:

```
<form method="post" id="add3">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="forms">
     <tbody>
       {% for lst in result %}
       <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ forloop.counter }}" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id">
       <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-expense" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-expense" value="{{lst.0}}"/>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-amount" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-amount" value="{{lst.1}}"/>
       </td>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is a short version. I have 6 fields in each row. I am able to get all 6 fields but it complains about the id. I have added the hidden `id` input type in each row but that doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: You template looks fine, and the issue could be in your views or forms. How is this formset generated? How is data validated? You need to provide more info.